# How to use outertheme infolines with one color?

Tags: beamer, themes

I want to use the outertheme infoline with one color. My style file `beamerthemeTest.sty` looks like this:

```
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\RequirePackage{pgf}

\definecolor{zhawblue}{HTML}{1166AD}
\setbeamercolor*{Title bar}{fg=white,bg=zhawblue}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{parent=Title bar}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{bg=zhawblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{fg=white,bg=zhawblue}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=white,bg=zhawblue}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=zhawblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=zhawblue}
\setbeamercolor*{separation line}{bg=zhawblue,fg=zhawblue}
\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{bg=zhawblue,fg=zhawblue}
```

[image]

But what resides is a small separation line between the panels. How can I remove them?

Thanks for any hints!
Cheers Reza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok got it to work I had to replace the `footline`, `headline` and `frametitle` with custom code (copied and modified from outertheme `shadow`, `split` and `infolines`):

```
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\RequirePackage{pgf}

\definecolor{zhawblue}{HTML}{1166AD}

\setbeamercolor*{corporatecolor}{fg=white,bg=zhawblue}
\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=white,bg=zhawblue}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{bg=zhawblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=octavelightgray,fg=octavegray}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{bg=white,fg=octavegray}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{fg=white,bg=zhawblue}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{fg=white,bg=zhawblue}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=zhawblue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=zhawblue}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
  color(0pt)=(bg);
  color(4pt)=(black!50!bg)
}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex]{corporatecolor}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}
        \insertshortauthor~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
        \insertshorttitle
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex]{corporatecolor}
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}
        \insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}
        \hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
      \end{beamercolorbox}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
  \vskip0pt%
  \vskip-0.2pt
  \pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}
  \vskip-2pt
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.3cm,left,wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \usebeamerfont{frametitle}%
      \insertframetitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
  \vskip-0.2pt
  \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
  \vskip-2pt
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east,xshift=-2pt,yshift=0pt] at (current page.north east) {
      \includegraphics[height=1cm]{images/zhaw_neg.pdf}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace*{-0.6cm}
}
```

And here's the result:
[image]

Comment: There's still one ugly issue, the vertical space between the frametitle and the text body. A workaround is tu use `\vspace*{-0.5cm}` in every slide, but I think it's ugly code.

Comment: try `\nointerlineskip` before the `beamercolorbox`

Comment: There's already one in `frametitle`. When I insert one in `headline` it's going to mess up the layout.

Comment: Inserting `\vspace*{-0.6cm}` in `frametitle` solved the problem, but it does not explain the cause?